# How to convert dates prior to 1970 in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

The following is a column from my data frame that is in a character format

```
             DateOfBirth
1:  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM
2:  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM
3: 11/1/2001 12:00:00 AM
```

I used the following piece of code to convert into a date format so I can calculate the age at a later stage

```
library(lubridate)

df$dob<-format(as.Date(df$DateOfBirth,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),format="%m-%d-%y")
df$dob<-mdy(df$dob)
```

However, the output for the date prior to 1970 results in the following way

```
             DateOfBirth        dob
1:  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM 2067-04-04
2:  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM 2067-04-04
3: 11/1/2001 12:00:00 AM 2001-11-01
```

How do I remedy the first two observations so that it the `dob` is `1967-04-04` instead of `2067-04-04`

Comment: You can specify the `origin`.  Not able to reproduce the issue though `as.Date("4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")#
[1] "1967-04-04"`

Comment: `as.Date(mdy_hms("4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM"))`

Comment: When you do `format="%m-%d-%y"` you go down to a two digit year. Instead to `format="%m-%d-%Y"` to keep the 4 digit year. But you are doing way more conversions than necessary. Us @d.b's answer for a more direct route.

Comment: @MrFlick: Did you mean @d.e ?  ;-)  `fortunes::fortune(112)` so I understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which parses this without requiring formats:

#### Code

```r
df <- data.frame(DateOfBirth=c("4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM", "4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM",
                               "11/1/2001 12:00:00 AM"))

df$date <- anytime::anydate(df$DateOfBirth)

df
```

#### Output

```r
R> df <- data.frame(DateOfBirth=c("4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM", "4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM",
+                                "11/1/2001 12:00:00 AM"))
R> df$date <- anytime::anydate(df$DateOfBirth)
R> df
            DateOfBirth       date
1  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM 1967-04-04
2  4/4/1967 12:00:00 AM 1967-04-04
3 11/1/2001 12:00:00 AM 2001-11-01
R>
```